# Why the data cannot be updated in this GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am a new ASP.NET developer and trying to use a GridView control to show all the employees in the employee table in the database. I am working now in enabling updating the information in the GridView. I am facing the following probelm and I don't know why:

**

> Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless
>   UpdateCommand is specified.

**

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

*(IsActive is like a flag (bit datatype) to indicate if the employee is in an assignment or not)*

ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
             CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
             BorderColor="#DEBA84" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
             OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
             OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true" />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                            DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobTitle")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 

            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.IsActive
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DivisionsListDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Divisions">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-Behind:

```
//For updating the information in any row in the GridView
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        DropDownList DivisionsList = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DivisionsList"); 

        TextBox txtEmployeeName = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtEmployeeName");
        TextBox txtJobTitle = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtJobTitle");
        TextBox txtBadgeNo = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtBadgeNo");

        CheckBox isActive = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("isActive");

        //For getting the ID (primary key) of that row
        string username = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        string name = txtEmployeeName.Text;
        string jobTitle = txtJobTitle.Text;
        string badgeNo = txtBadgeNo.Text;

        UpdateEmployeeInfo(username, name, jobTitle, badgeNo);
    }


    private void UpdateEmployeeInfo(string username, string name, string jobTitle, string badgeNo)
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                                                BadgeNo = @BadgeNo 
                            WHERE Username = @Username";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", badgeNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**So could you please help me in modifying this?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SqlDataSource` can do the updates in the database directly for you.

You don't need to capture the new values on row updating and do the updates on your own.

For this you need to set the `UpdateCommand`

Eg:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.IsActive
        FROM dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN dbo.employee
        ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, BadgeNo = @BadgeNo
        WHERE Username = @Username">

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>               
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: So you said there is no need for **UpdateEmployeeInfo** method?

Comment: Yes, if you specify the `UpdateCommand` the `SqlDataSource` will do it for you.

Comment: I am getting this new error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'UsersInfoDB.dbo.employee'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I don't know why I am getting it.

Comment: Your database doesn't allow nulls, and you have not bound the Name column to your gridview

Comment: I just added one letter to the existed name and it gave me this error.

Comment: User `Bind` instead of `Eval`. Eval does not bind your data to the columns.

Answer (score -1):

Your error really says it all. [Have a look at UpdateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx).

In you `UpdateEmployeeInfo` function try:

```
SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand =  @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = " + name + ", JobTitle = " + jobTitle + ", BadgeNo = " + badgeNo + " WHERE Username = " + username;
SqlDataSource1.Update();
```

Note: Not tested

Comment: I got the following error: 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'UsersInfoDB.dbo.employee'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated. '

Comment: Make sure that your @Name has a valid string value in it. The method that is calling UpdateEmployeeInfo might be passing and empty 'name' to the function.

Comment: I just added one letter to the existed name and it gave me this error.

Comment: I have updated the update string to more suit your problem. See my answer above now.

Comment: Ugh! This is asking for SQL Injection attacks! Avoid dynamic SQL in this way. Always use parameterized queries